# How to loop-mount RHEL 8 ISO of intallation disk on the directory /repo on VIRTUALBOX?

Tags: linux

How to configure system to automatically loop-mount the ISO of the installation disk on the directory /repo? (RHEL 8 install on Virtual Box)
could you please list and explain the steps to get this to work.

I downloaded Virtual Box then the ISO file for Rhel 8 to add it to my VM.
I am having trouble to complete this :

- how do I find the ISO file I downloaded on my laptop to get it for the VM?
- Would I use the path that is on my original laptop or is there a path on VirtualBox?

Below is what I tried.

- Do I need to update /etc/fstab?
- If needed to update /etc/fstab what would I enter (`\User\new\fake\desktop\disk.iso defaults 0 0`)?

There is a `/mnt` directory so I created a file in there.

```
root# cd /mnt/iso
root /mnt/fake# mount -t iso9960 -o loop \User\new\fake\desktop\disk.iso /mnt/iso
```

OUTPUT ---> "command": can't find in /etc/fstab

Answer (score 0):

Loop-mount is only applicable if you have VirtualBox Guest Additions already installed in your VM, and have VirtualBox configured to present a shared folder between your host and the VM. Then you would place the ISO file into the shared folder, first mount the shared folder with `mount -t vboxsf <share_name> <mount_point>`, then you could loop-mount the ISO file from within the shared folder, just as if existed as a local file.

For installation, you might not have the Guest Additions active, and so might not have the capability to mount VirtualBox shared folders yet. So it's better to just present the ISO as a virtual CD-ROM.

First, you'll need to have a virtual CD-ROM drive in the VM configuration. Then, when the VM is running, right-click a CD icon at the bottom row of the VM window, select `Choose a disk file...` and select the ISO file on your host system.
When you do that, it will be presented as a virtual CD-ROM, which will be mountable just like a real drive, so on the command line:

```
mkdir -p /repo  # just to ensure that the mount-point directory exists
mount -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /repo
```

To make the system mount the ISO automatically on boot, you would add this line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sr0 /repo iso9660 ro,nofail 0 0
```

(I would recommend using the `nofail` mount option with virtual CDs, to prevent the VM boot from getting stuck in emergency mode if the ISO image is no longer available.)

---

If you really want specifically a loop-mount, you would first have to configure VirtualBox to set up a shared folder between the host and the VM(s): at the top of a running VM's window, select `Devices` -> `Shared Folders` -> `Shared Folders Settings`, and click on the folder with a green plus sign at the right edge of the window to create a new shared folder. You'll need to specify the Folder Path as the path you wish to share on the desktop (e.g. `\User\new\fake\desktop` and a Folder Name for it (can be anything, let's say "hostdesk" for example).

If you don't want the VM to be able to write into the shared folder, check `Read only`; if you want the shared folder definition to persist when you shut down the VM and/or the host, check `Make Permanent`. You'll need to specify the `mount point` only if you check `Auto-mount` too. For this example, specify the mount point as `/mnt/hostdesk` and check `Auto-mount`. Then click OK to exit the shared folder properties dialog.

If you checked `Make Permanent`, the shared folder will appear in the list under "Machine Folders"; if not, it will be under "Transient Folders". The settings will take effect once you click OK one more time to exit the Settings dialog.

If the Guest Additions is active in your VM, the `/mnt/hostdesk` directory should now automatically appear and allow you to access the `\User\new\fake\desktop` folder on your host. Then to loop-mount the ISO:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/iso
mount -o loop,ro /mnt/hostdesk/disk.iso /mnt/iso
```

Since this loop mount can only be performed after the Guest Additions is successfully started, adding this loop mount to `/etc/fstab` without some precautions will likely cause the mount to be attempted too early in the boot process, resulting the system being stuck in emergency mode. You might try an entry like this:

```
/mnt/hostdesk/disk.iso /mnt/iso iso9660 loop,ro,nofail,x-systemd.requires=vboxadd-service.service 0 0
```

This tells `systemd` (which will translate the `/etc/fstab` lines into `.mount` units) that `vboxadd-service.service` must be running before this mount can be performed, and the `nofail` option ensures the system won't fail to boot if this mount fails for any reason.

See `man systemd.mount` for additional systemd-specific mount options.